# Shaderc (from conan) not linking in windows

Tags: c++, windows, linker-errors, conan

I am trying to build a project in debug mode that uses conan for dependency management.

Most dependencies seem to link fine but shaderc is failing with error:

```
shaderc.lib(shaderc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in winblows.cpp.obj [C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\buildvs\WinBlows@exe.vcxproj]
shaderc.lib(shaderc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in winblows.cpp.obj [C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\buildvs\Wi
nBlows@exe.vcxproj]
```

When I look online people suggest rebuilding the library in debug mode, I tried, I think, by doing:

`conan install . -if buildvs -s build_type=Debug -s compiler.runtime=MD -s compiler="Visual Studio" -s compiler.version=17 --build=missing`

But the error persists.

What can I do to link it?

Comment: The error means you are mixing Debug and Release. Your library needs to be match the same configuration as your application.

Comment: `compiler.runtime=MD` I believe thus should be `compiler.runtime=MDd` in the Debug configuration. It looks like the settings are trying to use the release runtime in debug mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, regardless of which of the 2 I use I get the exact same error. :\

Comment: You probably have the wrong `shaderc.lib` binary. There should be different/ separate binary libraries for Debug and Release. If I am reading correctly the one your project is trying to use was compiled in Release mode but you are trying to build your WinBlows project in Debug mode which causes the conflict.

Comment: I ended up deleting all of conan and my own directory and rebuilt everything from scratch. Seems to have worked